Issue with Azure Flask Webhook Setup for WhatsApp API
Hello fellow developers,
I hope you're all doing well. I am currently setting up a bot (LLM agent) using WhatsApp API and a Flask application hosted on Azure.
As recommended in Azure's tutorial, I have a startup.txt with the following command
gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 --chdir src/whatsapp_agent/whatsapp_agent run:app
which runs locally without an issue.
Once it is deployed on Azure, however, the webhook setting from WhatsApp API (Edit Whatsapp Business Account subscription) returns the following error:
The URL couldn't be validated. Callback verification failed with the following errors: curl_errno = 28; curl_error = Operation timed out after 6000 milliseconds with 0 bytes received; HTTP Status Code = 200; HTTP Message = Connection established
Did anyone run into a similar issue and managed to solve it?
Many thanks!

please share the code you tried in the above question
